# Cannot enter BytesIO with audio into AudioSegment.from_file correctly

Tags: python, streaming, pytube

I'm using PyTube to download an audio file from YouTube before converting it to an MP3. I want to do this using BytesIO.

My code is

```
yt = YouTube(youtube_link)
# Download file
audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
audio_bytes = io.BytesIO()
print('Getting audio bytes')
audio.stream_to_buffer(audio_bytes)
print('Converting format')
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(file=audio_bytes).export(io.BytesIO(), 'mp3')
return dcc.send_bytes(sound.getvalue(), f'{yt.streams[0].title}.mp3')
```

`AudioSegment.from_file` fails. The error is

```
    raise CouldntDecodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version 2022-07-04-git-dba7376d59-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 27.100 / 57. 27.100
  libavcodec     59. 36.100 / 59. 36.100
  libavformat    59. 26.100 / 59. 26.100
  libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
  libavfilter     8. 41.100 /  8. 41.100
  libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
  libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100
[cache @ 0000022fcb016200] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:0
cache:pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Just a guess: Try `audio_bytes.seek(0)` before calling `from_file`.

Comment: Thank you, @Michael. That worked, and this is the solution! What does `seek(0)` do? Reading the code I see: `Move to new file position and return the file position.` . May you elaborate?

Comment: Real files and simulated BytesIO files have a file pointer which determines where the next read or write operation in a file should happen. After the data was written to the file here, the file pointer was at the end of the file so reading from there returned nothing. The "seek(0)" set the pointer back to beginning.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much, @Michael. That makes sense and is consistent with my last comment. Truly appreciate your help here, and feel free to write up your answer so I may approve it as the solution.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Looked a while for this answer, would be great if it weren't just a comment (don't know if that is against SO SOPs but... future readers might thank you)

Comment: @user2305193 Done. Seems that I oversaw this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real files as well as simulated `BytesIO` files have a file pointer which determines where the next read or write operation in a file should happen. After the data was written to the simulated file `audio_bytes` with

```
audio.stream_to_buffer(audio_bytes)
```

the file pointer was at the end of the file so reading from there with

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(file=audio_bytes).export(io.BytesIO(), 'mp3')
```

returned nothing.

**Solution**:

Place a line

```
audio_bytes.seek(0)
```

between the above lines to set the file pointer back to beginning before reading.